# Object destructuring syntax with single item inside braces

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I came across this piece of code and I do not understand what it does:

```
const { LineClient } = require('messaging-api-line');
```

Now, I understand object assignment syntax when there are multiple variables inside the braces, for example:

```
let o = {p: 42, q: true};
let {p, q} = o;
```

But what is the difference between `const { LineClient }` and `const LineClient`?

Comment: Can you explain what `let {p, q} = o;` does? Is it assigning the `o` value to both `p` and `q`?

Comment: @Bergi it is the same as `let p = o.p; let q = o.q`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Comment: Yes. So what do you think `let {p, q, r} = o;` does then? And finally, what would `let {p} = o;` do?

Comment: @Bergi Haha yes I realized it now, haven't thought about it at first, got confused by a single item inside brackets. That's a nice pattern and I'm going to use it.

Comment: Object destructuring already exists in ES6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package exports of `messaging-api-line` look like [this](https://github.com/Yoctol/messaging-apis/blob/master/packages/messaging-api-line/src/index.js):

```
module.exports = {
  Line,
  LineClient,
};
```

---

So, doing this:

```
const { LineClient } = require('messaging-api-line');
```

will expose the exported `LineClient` class to your code. To instantiate the `LineClient` class, you can just do `const lc = new LineClient();`

---

On the other hand, doing this:

```
const LineClient = require('messaging-api-line');
```

will expose the entire exported object to your code. To instantiate the `LineClient` class you would have to do `const lc = new LineClient.LineClient();`, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
const LineClient  = require('messaging-api-line');
```

this will take the default export and assign it to variable `LineClient`, this variable can have any name

```
const { LineClient } = require('messaging-api-line');
```

this will take the export that has the exact **KEY** `LineClient` when there are multiple exports in the required module